# htaccess page numbers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I'm trying to build an htaccess file that displays an index file on a blank URI, or a numeric slug (pages), such as: example.com or example.com/12  (the later appending ?page=$1)

However when accessing any non-numeric slug, it should go to a different page.  For some reason, I can't get it to ever hit the index file (even when blank or numeric).  What am I missing?

Here's what I have:

```
Options All
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ another_page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Shouldn't a blank URI or numeric URI hit the first rule, with the Last flag, and load index.php?  Every request I make is hitting another_page.php

Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried adding "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" and "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" before the last line, thinking that'd stop some kind of recursion - to no avail.

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't like the '^' at the beginning of your regex, since it's not actually looking for the beginning of line?

Comment: You should aim to make your expressions as strict as possible. As it stands, your current rules are weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha, I figured it out shortly after posting this question.

I did require the RewriteCond lines above the final, but the original files had to exist too.  I setup this htaccess file before creating the index.php file (I was looking for a 404).

This is what worked:

```
Options All
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ another_page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Thanks guys!